# App Engine requires Java 1.7 or later

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt, glassfish

I have developed GWT application in Java 1.7, GAE 1.9.9, GWT 2.6.1 and Maven.
Now I realized that we have Glassfish server with Java 1.6.0_43 on it.
So I changed it, also change GWT to 2.1.1 to make app smaller, but Eclipse shows error: "App Engine requires Java 1.7 or later."
Tried to change GAE to 1.7.5 and 1.6.6 and the error stays.
I can't figure out what seems to be the problem.

What GAE should I use to compile my app with Java 1.6 and put it on Glassfish With Java 1.6?
Or it's not a GAE problem, but something else?

Also is it possible to put my gwt-servler.jar in Glassfish lib to make my war smaller? Than I could go back to GWT 2.6.1 and add some functionality to my app.

I don't need GAE at all if I publish to glassfish, just gwt-servler.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google app engine uses Java 7 which is now mandatory. On the GAE platform your webapps are running on Jetty servers.

Google App Engine Version 1.8.1 is the last which supports Java 6 (released in June 11, 2013). Since 1.8.2, the SDK only compiles with the Java 7 compiler and the only target runtime is Java 7.

Why do you need Glassfish + GAE + Java 6? If you develop for the GAE, you can't use Glassfish. The app engine sdk includes a bundled Jetty so you don't need it for developing, and certainly not for production.

If you don't develop for the App engine platform, then why do you need your project to be GAE project? Looks contradictory.

Either remove the GAE dependency (and libraries) from your project, or use Java 7 and not Glassfish (but the app engine SDK wich includes a bundled Jetty server).

**Edit:**

If you have Glassfish and you don't want to publish your webapp to Google App Engine, you don't need GAE at all. GWT also includes the Servlet apis which is useful for development, and Glassfish is an application server (servlet container) which contains the Servlet API implementation.

I think you got confused. The Google App Engine is a platform (platform as a service) and you ONLY have to make your project a GAE project and you ONLY have to add GAE libraries and dependencies IF you want to create and deploy your webapp specifically for the GAE platform.

Comment: I tried GAE 1.7.5 and it still throws the same error. It was not my choice to use GWT and publish app on Glassfhis. I just have to do what I'm told. With Java 1.7 everything worked fine and app is redy to deploy, but I have to make it work with Java 1.6 and on Glassfish 3.1, no choise for me here.

Comment: Would you please answer the questions I raised in this answer? You can edit your question to add these.

Comment: I guess I missunderstood use of GAE. But now I have another problem when I run GWT compile. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/persistence/Entity : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0. I have changed JAVA_HOME to 1.6, Eclipse default jre to Java 1.6, in pom.xml source and target is 1.6, but I get this error and in Event details of error: Message=GWT compilation failed and Session Data: java.version=1.7.0_60. Why?